# Where do I put the header tag in this twitter bootstrap situation?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm not sure if it matters where or how many times I insert the header tag in this code example.  I know it can be in the document more than one time, but is there a preferred or best practices guide for this situation?  Here is the code:

```
<body>
    <div id=cent>
        <div class="container">
            <div class=row>
                <header>  <!-- or Header tag here? -->
                <div class="clearfix hidden-xs col-sm-12 layering">
                    <img class="foreground trigger" src="img/Kedoshim-Logo.jpg" alt="Kedoshim Burning Logo on Mountain"/>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg col-xs-12 layering">
                    <img class="foreground trigger" src="img/Kedoshim-Logo-Mobile.jpg" alt="Kedoshim Burning Logo on Mountain"/>
                </div>
                </header>
            </div> <!-- close of row div for responsive headers -->
```

Can the header tag go around the whole row div or should it go around each image div or around each image?  Or inside the row div as I have shown?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: So long as header elements are not nested, which would be a validity error, any "best practice" is a matter of opinion and therefore off-topic for SO.

Comment: My appologies Alohci and others, I didn't realize this kind of question wasn't welcome here.  Best Regards.